# How to export Excel 2011 keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: ms-office

I customized my Excel 2011 shortcuts on my MacBook Pro and just wanted to have the same productivity level on my Mac Mini.

Is there a way I can export my Excel 2011 shortcuts or will I have to manually set them a second time?

I customized my shortcuts using System Preferences (I already manually set these 3 keyboard shortcuts again in Excel 2011 on my Mac Mini) or via the Customize Keyboard Shortcuts pane ( the one in the Tools menu if I remember well).

Comment: How did you customize your shortcuts ?

Comment: are we talking about keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: The question is "How to export Excel 2011 keyboards shortcuts?" So, I believe, yes, we are talking about keyboards shortcuts.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Via Excel keyboard shortcuts panel + Apple system preferences keyboard shortcuts panel.